Uniswap V3-sdk swaps WETH to any other ERC-20 tokens but not working for ERC-20 to WETH
I'm working on a project using the Uniswap V3 SDK and the @uniswap/smart-order-router to perform token swaps. My code successfully swaps WETH to any ERC-20 token. However, when I try to swap an ERC-20 token to WETH using the same code structure, the swap fails.
Here's the code that works for WETH to ERC-20 swaps:
// execute route function

export async function executeRoute(
    route: SwapRoute,
    wallet: ethers.Wallet,
    tokenIn: Token,
    amount: number
): Promise<TransactionState> {
    const walletAddress = wallet.address;
    const provider = wallet.provider;

    if (!walletAddress || !provider) {
        throw new Error('Cannot execute a trade without a connected wallet');
    }

    const tokenApproval = await getTokenTransferApproval(tokenIn, wallet, amount);
    console.log("Token approval: ", tokenApproval);

    if (tokenApproval !== TransactionState.Sent) {
        return TransactionState.Failed;
    }

    const { calldata, value } = route.methodParameters || {};

    if (!calldata || value === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Invalid route method parameters');
    }

    const res = await sendTransaction(wallet, {
        data: calldata,
        to: V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS,
        value: ethers.BigNumber.from(value),
        from: walletAddress,
        maxFeePerGas: MAX_FEE_PER_GAS,
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: MAX_PRIORITY_FEE_PER_GAS,
        gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(2000000),
    });

    console.log("Transaction sent with value: ", value);

    return res;
}


// send transaction function 
export async function sendTransaction(wallet: ethers.Wallet, transaction: ethers.providers.TransactionRequest) {
    try {
        const txResponse = await wallet.sendTransaction(transaction);
        console.log('Transaction hash:', txResponse.hash);

        const receipt = await txResponse.wait();
        console.log('Transaction was mined in block:', receipt.blockNumber);

        if (receipt.status === 1) {
            console.log('Transaction succeeded:', receipt);
            return TransactionState.Sent;
        } else {
            console.error('Transaction failed with status 0:', receipt);
            return TransactionState.Failed;
        }
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error('Error sending transaction:', error);
        if (error.code === 'CALL_EXCEPTION') {
            console.error('Call exception error:', error.transaction, error.receipt);
        }
        return TransactionState.Failed;
    }
}

// token approval function 

export async function getTokenTransferApproval(
    token: Token,
    wallet: ethers.Wallet,
    amount: number
): Promise<TransactionState> {
    const provider = wallet.provider;
    const address = wallet.address;

    if (!provider || !address) {
        console.log('No Provider Found');
        return TransactionState.Failed;
    }

    try {
        const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(
            token.address,
            ERC20_ABI,
            wallet
        );

        const amountToApprove = fromReadableAmount(
            amount,
            token.decimals
        ).toString();

        console.log("Amount to approve: ", amountToApprove);

        const transaction = await tokenContract.approve(
            V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS,
            amountToApprove
        );

        console.log("Approval transaction hash:", transaction.hash);

        const receipt = await transaction.wait();
        console.log('Approval transaction was mined in block:', receipt.blockNumber);

        if (receipt.status === 1) {
            console.log('Approval transaction succeeded:', receipt);
            return TransactionState.Sent;
        } else {
            console.error('Approval transaction failed with status 0:', receipt);
            return TransactionState.Failed;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error in approval transaction:', e);
        return TransactionState.Failed;
    }
}

Here is Error message when i tried to swap any other ERC-20 token to WETH

Error sending transaction: Error: transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (transactionHash="0xa08e245c413c625e4f0a9daa0eb68fd832058734af05db905099eab1336fe58a", transaction={"type":2,"chainId":1,"nonce":681,"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x174876e800"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x174876e800"},"gasPrice":null,"gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x1e8480"},"to":"0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},

Questions:

Are there any additional steps required specifically for swapping ERC-20 tokens to WETH?
Do I need to approve the WETH contract for spending the ERC-20 tokens beforehand? If so, how should I implement this approval?
Is there a different way to handle the value parameter for ERC-20 to WETH swaps compared to WETH to ERC-20 swaps?

Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
I expected the transaction for the ERC-20 to WETH swap to complete successfully, similar to the WETH to ERC-20 swap. Specifically, I expected the ERC-20 tokens to be swapped for WETH and the resulting WETH to be transferred to my wallet.
